# add button to leaflet popup used in lightning component

Tags: lightning, popup

Im trying to add button to leaflet popup in lightning component, I tried this:

```
var popupTemplate = '<div style="width:100%;border-bottom:1px black solid;">Project Details<span style="display:none;">#*#*</span></div><br/>'+
                        '<b style="color:black; font-size:12px;">Project Name:</b><a href="/pms/s/project-info/'+projectId+'"><span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;color:#800000;font-size:12px;width:110px;text-align:right; white-space:normal;" > '+projectName+
                      '</span></a><br /><br /><b style="color:black;font-size:12px;">Leader :</b><a href="/pms/s/detail/'+entityId+'"><span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;color:#800000;font-size:12px;" >  '+projectLeader;

                   if(isTime){
                        popupTemplate+=  '</span><br/><br/><br/><b class="smallPolygonLink" style="color:black;font-size:12px;border:1px solid #54585a;cursor:pointer;padding:8px;" onclick="self.openModel('+component+');">Add Comment3</b><br/><br/>';

                    }
```

.
.
.

```
 openModel: function(component, event, helper) {

    console.log("PPPPOOOO ");
        component.set("v.Open", true);
   }
```

but it does not work, the button is added but onclick event does not work